# incident angles between rays, falling on an oblique plane

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry

I am having really two simple questions, but following two things are confusing me.

**Question 1**

> If I know plane parameter (v3) of a given plane (say AB); if a pair of
>   rays are incident at a point on the plane (say, point - O), how can I
>   compute their incident angles (i.e. POC and POD), using *v1, v2, v3*? Where v1, v2 are
>   vectors along the incident rays.

[image]

**Question 2**

> Similarly, if I have many pairs of incident rays falling onto this plane, then, how can I really identify which pairs are making
>   *large angles* and which *are not* (i.e. DOC angle). I noticed that to get
>   DOC angle some time, I have to add both incident angles and some time
>   have to subtract them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***acute*** angle between two vectors can be defined using their [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):
$$
\cos\angle POC = \frac{|\mathbf{v}_1\cdot \mathbf{v}_3|}{\|\mathbf{v}_1\|\|\mathbf{v}_3\|},
$$
notice here an absolute value is added because $\mathbf{v}_1\cdot \mathbf{v}_3$ may be negative (actually negative based on your picture).

Similarly,
$$
\cos\angle POD = \frac{|\mathbf{v}_2\cdot \mathbf{v}_3|}{\|\mathbf{v}_2\|\|\mathbf{v}_3\|}.
$$

If you want to find the maximum of the *acute* angles between many pairs of incident rays, just find whose inner product is closest to $0$ (near perpendicular).